# Ignoring files for JavaScript autocomplete in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I'm wondering how to remove certain files form IntelliJ's autocomplete. More specifically things fetched via Maven. As an example, `replace` will generate a long list of declarations:

[image]

Most of which are random declarations of variables and functions in JS-files which come from Maven dependencies (I'm developing Confluence plugins, hence the Confluence dependencies). What I'm wondering is how I make IntelliJ ignore all these files? For files in the project I can simply mark the directory as ignored but since these files are in my Maven repository I can't do that.

Comment: any luck with this yet?

Comment: I'm afraid not, still looking.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the scope setting in IntelliJ to exclude files coming from libraries or other sources.

> The **scope** of a library defines the set of files and folders in which the library is considered as **library**, that is, it is write-protected, excluded from check for errors and refactoring, ***affects the completion list*** and highlighting.
>
> By default, all *predefined libraries* and *libraries downloaded from within IntelliJ IDEA* provide completion, resolution, highlighting and are treated as libraries in any file within the project. In other words, their usage scope is the whole project.
>
> *Libraries that you create yourself* are not considered libraries in any of the files unless you specify their usage scope explicitly.
>
> 1. *Open the Settings dialog*.
> 2. In the left-hand pane, expand the **JavaScript Libraries** node and select **Usage Scope**.
> 3. In the right-hand part (on the *Usage Scope page*):
>
>    - To make the library available in all the files within the project, click the **Library** cell in the topmost (**Project**) row and select the library in the list that appears.
>    - To specify a narrower usage scope, expand the nodes in the **File/Directory** column to see the folder or file you want to limit the library usage scope to. Click the **Library cell** to the right of the corresponding folder or file and select the library in the list.
> 4. Click **OK** in the **Settings** dialog.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#d76972e18833

Comment: This does not in any way help the issue. This is instructions regarding how to **add** more files to the autocomplete. I want to **remove** them.